# How to make View not go out of bound when manually adjusting x position

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I have a function that creates text view in a frame layout

```
val View1 = createTextView("hello12345678901234567890123456789012345")
   View1.y = 83F*0
   View1.x = 40F*0

val View2 = createTextView("hello12345678901234567890123456789012345")
   View2.y = 83F*2
   View2.x = 40F*5
```

View1 is fine. However, the problem is in View2. Since I need to randomize the position of x, View2 got out of bound and got cut off. I added a picture to illustrate.

[image illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4WAT.png)

How do I fix this?

Comment: it seems that the view's width is fixed, maybe you can make it dynamic so that it will adjust width based on x? or you could add a constraint on the range that can generate x

Comment: How do I make it dynamic? I just put the width and height as wrap_content on CreateTextView function.

Comment: The views are going to up to as wide as your FrameLayout if you use wrap_content. You need to set a specific width instead. Then make sure the X position you select is less than the FrameLayout width minus the inner view width. Note, X and Y are set in pixel units, not dp, so you also need to account for device screen size.

Comment: Actually, this is probably much easier with ConstraintLayout. You can randomize the horizontal bias in the horizontal constraints.

Comment: I am using a constraint layout as my parent. My framelayout (play area) is constraint to 4 borders (I used ImageView for borders) Can I still use ConstraintLayout bias?

Comment: But yeah I think it's easier to make sure the X position is within the layout